# WPF Application has 2 different names

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio-2010, assemblyinfo

My application has 2 different names, but I cannot find in the AssemblyInfo or anywhere in my project where the 2nd name is coming from.  It was called this a long while ago, but it was renamed since.

This is what my application title is from the assembly info.
[image: Application Name]

This is the other name of the application that I cannot find.
[image: 2nd application name]

Comment: I believe one is the name of the executable (bottom) and one is the name of the Window (top).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a red herring. I unpinned the application from the task bar, and re-pinned it.  They now both have the same name... it has just been sitting there since the change in name was made in the AssemblyInfo.